# How to check if css class is missing in SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, svg

I'm using a dynamic class to show a list of svg icons. I need to display a sample image only if a css class ("icon") is missing. How can I do this?

```
     <svg class="icon${Id} icon${Id}-dims" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
 width="40px" height="40px"></svg>
```

Note: ID is a variable i use to make SVG classes dynamic. I need to know when there are no matching classes available in CSS.
I have around 4000 icon classes.

Comment: Just making sure I understand correctly, you mean an example value for class would be something like ``class="icon$777 icon$777-dims"``? or will they likely be different values?

Comment: yes. a class name would be class=" icon1 icon1-dims"

Answer (score 3):

You can check like this also..

```
if(($('#test').attr('class')).indexOf("icon$") < 0) {


}
```

Comment: Thanx. But it doesnt seem to match my case :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pure JS approach.

```
//check for a specific 'icon' class
if(!document.querySelector('svg').classList.contains(`icon${Id}`)){
    console.log(`class icon${Id} not found`);
}
//check if no class contains 'icon' in its name
if(document.querySelector('svg').className.indexOf('icon') === -1){
    console.log(`Can not find class which has the word 'icon' in its name`);
}
```

*The above code uses ES6 strings template*.

Comment: @Ruby If you want to check if a class name exists in a style sheet, then your thinking is wrong. You should not set a class to an element which you don't want it to inherit css properties from the class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$st = $('svg').attr('class');
if ($st.slice(0,$st.indexOf(' ')) != $st.slice($st.indexOf(' ')+1,$st.indexOf('-'))) {
    alert('ch img')
//change img
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g9e3vcw3/2/

Comment: ID variable will always be filed,so there will always be a class name.I need to know when there are no matching css class for an icon.

Comment: if the id variable is missing the class attribute will look like this `class="icon icon -dims"` than you need to use `if ($('svg[class="icon"]').length > 0) {//add img}`

Comment: ID variable will always be filled.

Comment: you want to get all the svg that don't have the class starting with icon?

Comment: nope. I need to know when there are no exsisting css class  for my dynamic class name.

Comment: you mean whan a class atribute is like this `class="icon6 icon5-dims"` ?

Comment: yes. imagine class="icon6 icon5-dims" and there are no existing css for that. then i need to display a image.